# Moved from onprem to aws , selenium code which uses reflection is not working on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

We have recently moved to AWS , one of the testcases uses reflection to work with types and fields in an assembly, and it creates a `RadWindow` instance in a Selenium-based automation script.

We were doing the above to click a control and handle popup .Iframe was not getting supported on this page so we used reflection , now the mentioned code is failing and none of the controls are getting identified in popup. There is no issue with Main window
I tried `WindowHandles`

```
var windowHandles = driver.Instance.WindowHandles.ToList();
```

his is also retuning 1 both onprem and aws .
This code was working fine in onprem but on AWS its failing , anyone has any insight about it .

Please help its a blocker .

```
   var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
   var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Page)));
   var props = typeof(PageName).GetFields();
   var val = props[0].GetValue(null);
   var testClass = new PageName();
   Object objInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(PageName));
   return new RadWindow(driver.Instance, "rwGenericPageName");
```

The above code is not identifying the popup